# How to access oracle database (VB.NET)

Tags: oracle, vb.net-2010, system.data.oracleclient

I am new to use oracle and i have a problem of accessing it in a mvc controller.

Here is the connectionstring i defined in web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=abc;Persist Security Info=True;password=123; User Id=user1;"
           providerName="System.Data.OracleClient=" />
</connectionStrings>
```

How to access this DB in the controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which framework you're using for data access.

But, if you're using pure ADO.NET, you could take a look on that tutorial: [Advanced Data Access with ADO.NET and Oracle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971488.aspx)